# Paperclip: Download all files in a compressed format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, paperclip

In rails 3.2.13, I am using paperclip gem for file uploads. I want all attachments to download in a zipped folder.

I am using below gem

```
rubyzip (1.1.3)
```

If I use below code, will get an error like "uninitialized constant Zip::ZipFile"

```
@assets = Assets::Resume.all

tmp_filename = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/tmp_zip_" <<
  Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S").to_s <<
  ".zip"
Zip::ZipFile.open(tmp_filename, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zip|
  @assets.each do |e|
    zip.add("#{e.document.original_filename}", e.document.url)
  end
end

send_data(File.open(tmp_filename).read, :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename =>"#{current_user.id}_cvs.zip")
File.delete tmp_filename
```

To overcome this problem I have modified this code as mentioned below. After this modification, I am getting one .zip file with empty data(no files).

```
@assets = Assets::Resume.all

tmp_filename = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/tmp_zip_" <<
  Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S").to_s <<
  ".zip"
Zip::File.open(tmp_filename, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip|
  @assets.each do |e|
    zip.add("#{e.document.original_filename}", e.document.url)
  end
end

send_data(File.open(tmp_filename).read, :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename =>"#{current_user.id}_cvs.zip")
File.delete tmp_filename
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try e.document.path instead of e.document.url.

Comment: After that also I am getting empty .zip file.

Comment: Do a puts "e.document.path" in the each loop and see if its printing proper in the log/stdout. Also check for permission issues for creating tmp_filename in the tmp dir of rails root.

Comment: puts "e.document.path" is not printing. Loop is not executing.

Comment: Means @assets is empty. Check how you are fetching all assets to be downloaded. I dont thin `@assets = Assets::Resume.all` is working.

Comment: Yes. I fixed this @assets issue. For testing purpose I have uploaded some duplicate files but now I am getting an error like "add failed. Entry 240392.pdf already exists".